# Set the title property of html button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one button with its corresponding ID. I wish to set the tooltip property of it with JS.

```
<button name="subject" id="button" type="submit" value="HTML" title="title1">HTML</button>

<script>   
function clickMe() {
    $('#button').title = 'title2';
} 
</script>
```

How am I able to do this ? Is it title property or some other ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `$('#button').attr('title') = 'title2';` or `$('#button').prop('title', 'title2');`

Answer (score 4):

use prop function, as you are using jquery.

```
$('#button').prop('title', 'title2');
```

if using plain javascript (no jquery)

```
document.getElementById('button').title = 'title2';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set the title attribute by

```
$("#button").attr('title', 'title2');
```

Like this you can give/ define any attribute to html element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#button" ).attr( "title", "title2" );
```

Answer (score 0):

var element = $('#yourElementId');

**//Get or Set an element's title property with jQuery (v1.6+)**

element.prop('title', 'your new title');

**//Get or Set an element's title attribute with jQuery (versions <1.6)**

element.attr('title', 'your new title');